# Extremely small issue by playing a sound

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have this in my `PlaceholderFragment` `onCreateView`

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.maria);
mp.start();
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope
```

Why `MainActivty.this` is not working? What am I missing here? I know that it is extremely small thing, but I'm not able to spot it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MainActivity.this` only works inside `MainActivity`. Use `getActivity()` in a `Fragment`:

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.maria);
```

Comment: Now the sound won't start :(

Comment: check your device volume when starting the song

Comment: oh now it plays fine :P

Answer (score 2):

This happen because you dont have access to your Main activity in this line.

If you are calling it from fragment you should use getActivity();

```
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.maria);
```

if you are trying to call MainActivity.this from a static method or from another class

you should use context.

its also help if you Can you add your full code.